# How to return an array received from fetching api data in a .then statement?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to export an array inside a .then statement but its not working. I have no clue how to make it work otherwise. Actually I'm just trying to set my initial state in redux to this static data I am receiving from the movie database api.

```
import { API_URL, API_KEY } from '../Config/config';

const urls = [
`${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
`${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=2`,
]

Promise.all(urls.map(items => {
return fetch(items).then(response => response.json())
}))

.then(arrayOfObjects => {
var arr1 = arrayOfObjects[0].results;
var arr2 = arrayOfObjects[1].results;
export var movieData = arr1.concat(arr2);   
}
)
```

Comment: would you please tell me your scenario? do you want fetch movies list in this file save it in redux?

Comment: you can export the promise and wherever you are importing use .then(...). also, add your piece of code where you want to use this exported data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear where this code is in relation to your state/reducer, but ideally you should be using action creators to deal with any API calls and dispatch state updates, and those action creators can be called from the component.

So, initialise your state with an empty array:

```
const initialState = {
  movies: []
};
```

Set up your reducer to update the state with `MOVIES_UPDATE`:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case 'MOVIES_UPDATE': {
      return { ...state, movies: payload };
    }
  }
}
```

You can still use your function for fetching data:

```
function fetchData() {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(items => {
    return fetch(items).then(response => response.json());
  }));
}
```

..but it's called with an action creator (it returns a function with dispatch param), and this action creator 1) gets the data, 2) merges the data, 3) and dispatches the data to the store.

```
export function getMovies() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetchData().then(data => {
      const movieData = data.flatMap(({ results }) => results);
      dispatch({ type: 'MOVIES_UPDATE', payload: movieData });
    });
  }
}
```

And it's called from within your component like so:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.props.dispatch(getMovies());
}
```

Comment: Hey it gives me this error => Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Comment: Add [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) as middleware and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a function. like this:

```js
import { API_URL, API_KEY } from '../Config/config';

export const getMovies = () => {
   const urls = [
   `${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
   `${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=2`,
  ]

  const promises = urls.map(url => {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
     fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => resolve(res.results))
    })
  })

  return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

// other file

```js
import {getMovies} from 'YOUR_API_FILE.js';

getMovies().then(moviesArr => {
   // your business logics here
})
```

Comment: By doing that I'd have to use the .then logic inside my reducer

Comment: no! if you want to put it in your redux then use redux middleware like redux-thunk or saga! these middlewares are used to make async calls in redux!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code as below:

```
import { API_URL, API_KEY } from '../Config/config';
let movieData='';

exports.movieData = await (async function(){

const urls = [
`${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`,
`${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=2`,
];

const arrayOfObjects = await Promise.all(urls.map(items => {
return fetch(items).then(response => response.json())
}));

 return arrayOfObjects[0].results.concat(arrayOfObjects[1].results);
 })();
```

Comment: `exports.movieData = await ...` how await supposed to be there without async?

Comment: Sort of works but now the the function is returning a promise which stays in pending state